# CSS height 100% bug in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I have the following html:

```
<html>
    <head> … </head>
    <body>
        <div id="entireContent">
            <div class="header"> … </div>
            <div id="contentBody"> … </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following css:

```
#entireContent {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 83px;
}

#contentBody {
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(45, 87, 40);
    height: calc(100% - 83px);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

In chrome everything it's ok. the contentBody stretches all over the remaining height.
But in firefox add some white space (like 30px) down under the  tag..
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try `max-height: 100%;`

Comment: I don't see much difference: http://jsfiddle.net/wUBC2/ Are you using quirks mode or standards compliance mode?

Comment: I just fiddled your code, and get the same display on firefox as well as chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/wS9EW/ Let me know if I/you have missed anything. - @user2361682

Comment: You're using the calc function, so the question is, what versions of the browsers are you using? Firefox only supports the unprefixed function since v16, and Chrome since v26. For older browser versions, you should include the ones with the vendor prefixes as well. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Answer (score 1):

Did you removed the html default margins? You should have also the wekbit prefixed version for box-sizing(because you used border with box-sizing set to border-box only for mozilla)

```
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

It displays same on firefox and chrome. The issue may be caused by the contents inside the <"contentBody"> Maybe you can try removing some of the content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: zoom on your firefox could just be screwing up display. Adjust to 100% and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's caused by some special plugin or addon in your Firefox browser. I met exactly same problem as yours, I tried everything and later found it was cause be a Xunlei Thunder plugin in Firefox browser, it added 30px white bar under my page. After I disabled it, the white bar disappear, showing exactly same result as in Chrome browser.